# $.ajax callback function is inside another function

Tags: jquery

I am having one function which will be called when ever my custom controls get loaded. please refer below code.

```
function load()
{
getdata();
}

function getdata()
{

  $. ajax({
 url://remote url,
type:"get",
success:function(data)
{
//going to set the data to my control
}

});
}
```

so success callback function takes some time to return the "data" (i.e fetch the data from remote URL) but load() client side method gets completed and do our control rendering. so i want  load() method needs to  wait until success function return the data from remote URL and then load() function get completed then i will render our control based on the data.

how to do load() function need to wait the callback gets completed.

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: The direct answer to your question is that you want to add async: false to the AJAX request to make the browser wait for the request to finish. In reality you want to structure your application in such a way that you don't need to do this, as you are fighting the event-based nature of javascript and the beauty of AJAX because you want it to fit with your code.

Comment: There is no way of making function x wait for function y to complete before returning something.

Answer (score 4):

1) Place the client side rendering code inside of your success handler...

2) Separate it into another method and call that from the success handler.

Both approaches will solve the problem of your load function completing and causing your UI to render before your data returns.

Comment: That's two answers you have been given that were completely valid and you have commented the same thing. I'd venture to say that I'll take the downvote just to show that you are rejecting valid answers with no cause. Your specifications are spotty at best, and your requirements have been filled. I'll remove this if you show me why this is a bad answer.

Comment: even this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16446618/1257652 is saying pretty much the exact thing I am. So either you are not specific enough, or you need to rephrase your question..

Comment: @SivaRajini Either you have to ask for clarification or explain why this solution doesn't work for you. Just crying "bad solution" doesn't help anyone to give you a better answer.

Comment: palo provides correct solution "async: false". other solutions are not useful for me. sorry for u guys..don't downvote me.

Comment: Siva - don't use async:false.  It may solve your problem in the short term, but it's a bad idea and isn't compatible with the nature of ajax requests.  Sometimes you have to change what you are doing to in order to avoid a bad practice.  Brett is right and you are wrong here.

Comment: @SivaRajini `async: false` is the worst way of solving this issue. That is a flaw in your logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a callback function in load() like this..

```
function load()
{   
  getdata(function(data){
      alert('done')
      // do something with data             
  });

}

function getdata(cb)
{

    $. ajax({
    url:"..",
    type:"get",
    success:function(data)
    {
      //send data back to load
      cb(data);
    }

    });
}

load();
```

Comment: how can i send back data to load here.

Comment: ?? Once the ajax returns to success it passes 'data' to the callback function passed to it by the load function. Look at comments in the other answer.